# Почему при применении стиля к группе элементов по id, меняется только первый?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Скриптом хочу задать видимость пунктов меню для разных категорий пользователей.

В блоке `if` все работает корректно, то есть пункты `#for_log` скрываются все.
Но в `else` скрывается только один первый пункт из всего списка `#forguest`.

Подскажите, почему?

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    if (document.getElementById('pun-status').innerHTML.match("Гость")=="Гость")
    {
      document.getElementById('for_log').style.display="none";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById('forguest').style.display="none";
    }
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-image: url('http://forumstatic.ru/files/0012/bb/27/62658.png');
background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px; 
width:90%;
border:none; 
top:10px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:10px;
position:fixed;
z-index:100;
overflow-y:auto;
font-size: 20px; 
text-align: center; 
color: #9f4306;
visibility: hidden;"
id="mobile_vis">
  <div class="dropdown" style="width:100%;">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn" style="float: right;"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" style="width: 100%; align: right;                  background-color: transparent; padding-top:50px;">
      <a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru">
        <img src="http://forumstatic.ru/files/0012/bb/27/44140.jpg" alt="Форум"/>
      </a>
      <a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru/userlist.php">
        <img src="http://forumstatic.ru/files/0012/bb/27/17305.jpg" alt="Избранные"/>
      </a>
      <a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru/search.php">
        <img src="http://forumstatic.ru/files/0012/bb/27/49924.jpg" alt="Поиск"/>
      </a>
      <a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru/messages.php" id="for_log">
        <img src="http://forumstatic.ru/files/0012/bb/27/67549.jpg" alt="Почта"/>
      </a>
      <a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru/login.php" id="forguest">
        <img src="http://forumstatic.ru/files/0012/bb/27/78584.jpg" alt="Вход"/>
      </a>
      <a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru/register.php" id="forguest">
        <img src="http://forumstatic.ru/files/0012/bb/27/58635.jpg" alt="Регистрация"/>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Применять по id группе элементов неправильно. Правильнее будет применять свойства по классу элемента.

Comment: id - идентификатор, на странице не должно быть много элементов с одним и тем же id. Он как бы идентифицирует элемент однозначно. Найдёт первый и дальше искать не станет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> пункты `#for_log` скрываются все

Потому что у Вас этих пунктов - один.

> скрывается только один первый пункт из всего списка `#forguest`

Потому что `document.getElementById` и возвращает один элемент - первый найденный по `id`.

```
else
{
  document.querySelectorAll('.forguest').forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
  });
}

<a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru/login.php" class="forguest">
...
<a href="http://towerofgod.quadrobb.ru/register.php" class="forguest">
```